# Docker attach to multiple containers

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

My problem is the following:
I'm running docker-compose using a makefile where I spin up groups of containers in a loop.

I end up with multiple groups, named similarly:

```
node1_service1_1, node1_service2_1, node1_service3_1,
node2_service1_1, node2_service2_1, node2_service3_1,
node3_service1_1, node3_service2_1, node3_service3_1
```

If I spun up these groups separately in non-detached mode, I'd see the output of all containers in each group in a separate window, combining the output using colour-coded labels like so:

```
node2_service1_1   | PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
node2_service1_1   | To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:
node2_service3_1   | Enabling web-ui
node2_service1_1   | 
node2_service3_1   | Enabling plugins on node rabbit@dc37ca9dfa34:
node2_service3_1   | rabbitmq_management
```

However, I need to run docker-compose in detached mode (-d) in order to spin up all groups before starting my actual application. I also noticed using -d is much faster than not using it.

My first idea was to just `docker attach` to multiple containers. Unfortunately only one container is supported at a time.

I then tried to group commands in bash like so:

```
{ docker attach --no-stdin=true node2_service1_1 \
& docker attach --no-stdin=true node2_service2_1 \
& docker attach --no-stdin=true node2_service3_1; }
```

which *does* work, **but** without the colour and without the labels, meaning I cannot tell which line was printed by which container.

**Question:**
Is there a way of attaching to multiple (detached) containers in the same way as one would be "attached" to them when running docker-compose in non-detached mode?
Alternative suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you don't really need to attach to these containers if you only need their output (logs). `docker-compose` allows to view color-coded logs from all running containers using [`docker-compose logs`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/) command. Combine it with [regular flags](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/) for `docker-compose` command (file, project, etc.), and you'll get color-coded logs of multiple "nodes".

Comment: Woohoo, thank you, that's exactly what I needed! For some reason I had assumed logs are just files.